# Not showing the repeated value on tooltip from ng-repeate

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I want to show users name on list on tooltip like:
'user1 and 5 others', when I hover over '5 others', It will show all 5 users name(user2, user3 ..) on tooltip. For this I am using Angular-bootstrap.

here is my code:

```
<div ng-repeat="c in classes">
   <span ng-if = 'c.users.length > 1'>
     <h2> {{c.users[0].name}}</h2>
     | &
     <a href="#" tooltip="<ul><li ng-repeat='u in c.users'>{{u.name}}</li></ul>"> 
        {{invention.newInventer.length-1}} Others  
    </a>
  </span>
</div>
```

It is showing full condition as a string(not showing user name). How can I get all users name on tooltip?

Comment: are you are c.users containing the data as you want? can you show example data?

Comment: I have a classes scope, in there users array exist like:  $scope.classes = [{className: 'class1', users: [{users: 'user1'}, {users: 'user2'}, {users: 'users3'}]}, {className: 'class2', users: [{users: 'user11'}, {users: 'user22'}, {users: 'users33'}]}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 You should use `tooltip-html-unsafe` [instead of `tooltip` attribute](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tooltip):

> There are two versions of the tooltip: tooltip and tooltip-html-unsafe. The former takes text only and will escape any HTML provided. The latter takes whatever HTML is provided and displays it in a tooltip; it called "unsafe" because the HTML is not sanitized. The user is responsible for ensuring the content is safe to put into the DOM!

2 Replace you `ng-repeat` with custom function that will be executed each time and will create html for tooltip, like the following:

```
  $scope.getUsersList=function(users){
    var html=angular.element("<ul/>");
    angular.forEach(users,function(value){
      html.append("<li>"+value.name+"</li>");
    });
    return html.html();

  };
```

and html:

```
<a href="#" tooltip-placement="bottom" 
      tooltip-html-unsafe="{{getUsersList(users)}}">Check me out!</a>
```

Take a look at example in **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/j7Z7yXQx32TJVCiD5wug?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks @nicolai for your valuable answer

Answer (score 0):

```
app.directive('tooltipDirective', ["$compile", function($compile){
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: false,
            link: function(scope, element, attrs){
                attrs.$observe('tooltipDirective',function(value){
                    element.tooltip({trigger: 'hover',placement:'bottom',title:value});
                });
            }
        }
    }]);


html:
<a href="#" tooltip-directive="<ul><li ng-repeat='u in c.users'>{{u.name}}</li></ul>"> 
        {{invention.newInventer.length-1}} Others  
    </a>
```